# MySQL Entity Framework not saving the data

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am using following code to save the data into `MySQL` database.

```
DBEntities odbb = new DBEntities();

test_tba oinst_tba = new test_tba();
oinst_tba.agent_id = agent.Id;
oinst_tba.instruction_id = sCaseId;
oinst_tba.accept = 0;
oinst_tba.sms_id = "";

odbb.test_tba.Add(oinst_tba);
odbb.SaveChanges();
```

It's not saving the data into the database.

Following points :

- No error is thrown.
- Table does have a primary key
- If I check the object after calling `SaveChanges`, it shows the incremented id in the object
- Also, if I save value in database it's saving data with next incremented id that of object after calling `SaveChanges()`

Comment: Did you happen using a BeginTransaction() ?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant properties of `oinst_tba`, `agent` and `instruction`? How do you get objects `agent` and `sCaseId`?

Comment: agent id and caseid are values - even I tried with hard coded values and passing test_tba id (primary key as 0)

Comment: @MaulanaMango I am not using transaction